# How to do a Hibernate bulk insert

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a scenario where I need to insert 10, 000 rows in database. I am thinking to have insertion through parallel threads. However, just wondering if there is a way in hibernate to do a batch insert. Like addBatch in java.sql.Statement and executeBatch

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Batch inserts are covered in the user manual, [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch-insert).

You have the choice of using a `Stateful` or a `Stateless` session.  Each case has its own set of advantages and disadvantages depending on your use case.

The documentation provides examples of how to implement either case but ultimately it boils down to your code handling transactions in a loop with decent batch / bucket sizes for each transaction.